# iOS How to Send string Class 1 to Class2

Tags: ios

Class1 i have

textClass1 = @"Hello"

how to send String to Class2

Label.text = textClass1 ?

Thank you :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your **Class1.H** set a `protocol`:

```
@protocol Class_1_Delegate
@optional
- (void) ASimpleFunction:(NSString*)val;
@end
```

in any class where do you want to get the value, add delegate (in the .H) like this:

```
@interface Class2 : UIViewController <Class_1_Delegate> { }
```

Now, implement in **Class2.M** your

```
- (void) ASimpleFunction:(NSString*)val {
}
```

and remember to set delegate for class1!

`class1.delegate = self` (class2)

it's all!
Now, you are able to call `ASimpleFunction` from any classes that implements your protocols!

If you don't like this way, see `NSNotifications` from apple docs.

hope this helps.